# Inferring Type from a Type's Base Class in a Generic Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, generics, reflection

I know the title may be a little confusing, but let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish..

---

Let's suppose I have the **class**

```
public class TestA<T>
{
    public T Key { get; set; }
}
```

And the **class**

```
public class TestB : TestA<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `TestB` inherits from `TestA<int>`, and therefore inherits the property `public int Key`

---

Now, let's add an **interface**

```
public interface TestC<T> where T : TestA<X>
{
    T DoSomething(X argument);
}
```

And here's where I'm having trouble.

I want the `DoSomething` method, to take an argument of whatever the type the super class of `T` (`TestA<>`) is, in the case of `TestB`, that would be `int`.

So, if I had an implementation of type `TestC<TestB>`, I want the `DoSomething` signature to be:

```
public TestB DoSomething(int argument);
```

The problem is that `TestA<X>` does not compile and I can't manage to achieve this

---

Please, do you know if this is possible to do? If so, could you explain me how?

Maybe I can manage something with *Reflection*?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add the generic argument for the type you're missing, in this case, `X`:

```
public interface TestC<T, X> where T : TestA<X>
{
    T DoSomething(X argument);
}
```

Comment: why we need to add it in ``TestC``, did'nt got it

Comment: I don't want to add it manually and pass it as a generic argument, I want the compiler to infer it :(

Comment: @MatiCicero You can't do that.  You need to specify it manually.

Comment: @EhsanSajja Why wouldn't you need to add it?  He wants to have two different generic types.  To do that he'll need to define two generic arguments.

Comment: @Servy can you explain what it means by adding x with comma seperated

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's declaring a new generic argument, as I said in my answer.  You can declare as many generic arguments as you want, yes.

Comment: @Servy Why can't I do it? Is there an explanation?. The type can be inferred at compile time

Comment: @Servy can you provide some good resource to make good understanding of generics?

Comment: @MatiCicero Because that's the way the language was designed.  What else do you expect to hear?  Why are you so radically opposed to typing out *just two characters of text*.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad [Sure](https://www.google.com/search?q=generics&oq=generics&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1785j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+generics)

Comment: I refuse to hear that, @Servy

Comment: @MatiCicero Then you refuse to hear it.  It won't change the facts.

Comment: See my answer, there IS a way to do it

Comment: @MatiCicero Your answer *doesn't* do it though.

Answer (score -1):

There is a possible solution too:

```
public interface TestC {
    T DoSomething<T,X>(X x) where T : TestA<X>;
}

public class TestCImpl : TestC {
    public T DoSomething<T,X>(X x) where T : TestA<X>
        //Do something
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

This one compiles, but is easy to get runtime exceptions, due to the fact that IntelliSense does not seem to work and infer the `x` argument's type.

For instance, both of these compiles:

```
TestC c = new TestCImpl();
c.DoSomething<TestB>(2);
c.DoSomething<TestB>("Hello");
```

But only the first one should really work, as `TestB` inherits from `TestA<int>`

Comment: 1) That's not equivalent code to what the OP is asking for. 2) C# will never infer some but not all of the generic arguments.  It's an all or nothing thing.  Your assertion that either of those examples compiles is false, at least for the code shown.

Comment: 1) It's not equivalent, but it is a workaround for the compiling problem **and** for the fact that I don't need to specify explictly the type of my parameter or argument

Comment: No, it doesn't.  On top of the fact that, as mentioned, C# will never infer a partial list of generic arguments, you're invoking the constructor of an interface.  That of course will never compile.  For your second snippet to compile `TextC` would need to have a radically different definition than what you've shown.  Either your first or your second snippet could compile, but they both can't compile together.

Comment: I'm telling you it does

Comment: Then either you didn't provide the actual code you're using, your code doesn't actually compile despite your assertions, or you're not using a C# compiler.  It will fail with the error: `Using the generic method 'TestC.DoSomething<T,X>(X)' requires 2 type arguments`